# jboss external file access

Tags: url, jboss, contextpath

I'm trying to access files external to a given website/context (say, images common to several websites).  I've set up jboss-web.deployer/server.xml with:

```
<Context path="/questionbank" docBase="/usr/local/jboss-eap-4.3.0.GA_CP01/jboss-as/server/commonDir/questionbank" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

I access the files via a URL:

```
url = "http://localhost:8080/questionbank/some/file/path.htm";
URL file = new URL(url);
reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(file.openStream()));
```

This works when I'm debugging in Ecplise, using a local jboss instance (Windows XP and 7).  The jboss version is 4.3.0.  However, when I deploy to my Linux server, I get a ConnectException, "connection refused".

I've tried omitting the "8080" and I've tried an explicit path:

```
http://my.server.com/thecontext/questionbank/some/file/path.htm
```

Omitting the 8080, I get the same ConnectException.  Using the hostname, I get a 302 error, with the correct url in the redirection link.

Any thoughts on what I'm leaving out?

Comment: For anyone who comes across this: After trial and error, I was able to get things working simply by using the explicit IP address for the system/node.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this: After trial and error, I was able to get things working simply by using the explicit IP address for the system/node. Problem solved!